# Acces To 'COM' is Denied on SerialPort

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I'm making a dll in c# for connecting EDC to PC , and show it on Internet explorer with USB port,On the first try, it success, the code is connect to EDC, EDC throws a value, convert it to xml, and show the xml at Internet explorer, when i try it again, the internet explorer throws the execption 'Access to COM is denied', when i close the internet explorer, the code is running again, and when i tried again, it throws the same value.

how to fix it ? Please help, i really new to these SerialPort

I searched on internet, that they suggest to close the port after open it, i tried it but it still throws an execption.

C# Code for Sending and Receive

```
 public string CobaAja(string a)
{    
    SerialPort port;
    port = new SerialPort(com, p);
    port.Parity = Parity.None;
    port.BaudRate = 9600; //115200
    port.DataBits = 8;
    port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    port.RtsEnable = true;

    //sending
    port.Open();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(a);
    port.Write(messageSent, 0, messageSent.Length);

    //receive
     string data;
     string xmlBuild;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[port.ReadBufferSize];
     int bytesToRead = port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     while ((bytesToRead = port.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
     {
          data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
           //these are the codes for creating XML 
           //After creating XML, i try to return the xml value 
           xmlBuild = sb.ToString();
           return xmlBuild;
      }
          port.close();
          return a;
    }
```

javascript code for call the dll and show the results on console

```
var objPP = new ActiveXObject("Nyoba.Dulu");
 var coba = objPP.CobaAja(xml);
 console.log(coba);
```

Comment: When you `return` from within `while` your port isn't closed.

Comment: You can only open a port once and must close before opening a second time.  You must be getting to the open statement multiple times.

Comment: are you sure the code between port.open() and port.close() doesn't throw any exceptions? because if it did even once, you won't be able to open it again until you either close that instance or do hardware reset on the COM port (e.g. using System's Device Manager; restarting your computer will work too...). You may reduce the risk of this problem happening by using the following "hack" https://stackoverflow.com/a/5218982/891715